# When using neural networks, should I bin the continuous variables and apply some transformation before performing variable selection and modeling?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, data-preprocessing, feature-selection

I come from a background of scorecard development using logistic regression. Steps involved there are:

1. binning of continuous variables into intervals (eg age can be binned into 10-15 years, 15-20 years, etc)
2. weight of evidence transformation
3. coarse classing of bins to ensure event rate has a monotonic relationship with the variable

Variable selection is made from the coarse classed transformed variables.

I was wondering if I should follow the same steps for ANN models. That is, should I bin the continuous variables and apply some transformation before performing variable selection and modeling.

Comment: My guess is continous will give better results. Although it's probably dependent on the dataset, so the only one who can answer your question is you.